# Crontab, execute a task a random number of times within a period of time

Tags: cron

I want to use cron to run a task a random number of times every 3 minutes and 30 seconds, between 8 a.m. and 6 p.m. They could help me with this problem. I've been searching, but I have not managed to do it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would address the issue two ways - depending on the requirement:

- if you mean that a task may be executed or not at random, every 3 minutes and 30 seconds between 8am and 6pm, you can add some random number generation and execute if matches certain criteria (number greater than x or divisible by y, etc)
- if you mean that the task should be executed random N times for each trigger occurring every 3 minutes 30 seconds between 8am and 6pm, you could use a random number to specify how many times to execute and then loop until reaching that number of executions.

As for the cron, you may find [this page](https://crontab.guru/) useful to assemble it :)

### EDIT

Here a follow-up on the comment, that the use case refers to the second one I mentioned above:

**script**

```
random_times=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
for i in `seq 1 $random_times`; do bash /path/to/script.sh; done
```

**crontab**

```
*/3 * * * *
```

Please notice, that if using unix crontab, you do not have seconds granularity and thus will execute every 3 minutes.

Comment: exactly as you describe in point # 2, could you help me achieve it? I do not have many skills in bash

Comment: Above the edited answer - please accept if you find it solves the issue :)

Comment: Thanks, right now I'm going to try it, if it works without a doubt, I'll mark you as a 'solution' .. referring to the use of the seconds, I was reading, and I found the following solution: ``*/3 08-18 * * * sleep 30; command``